# IOS8 Uiscrollview Inside uiview Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

In IOS8 i cant added UIView below of UIScrollView.The code i have used is as below as

```
UIScrollView *MainScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
MainScroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
MainScroll.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 365,470);
[self.view addSubview:MainScroll];

UIView *HeaderView=[[UIView alloc]init];
HeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
HeaderView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,width,20);
[MainScroll addSubview:HeaderView];
```

In this Code HeaderView is not placed at starting point of MainScroll.It is placing after some spaces from UIScrollView.This problem is happening only in IOS8.But in IOS7 it is working fine what i expected.

Comment: are you using iOS 8 Beta version?Bcz your code is working fine in iOS7 & iOS8.

Comment: s this s beta version

Answer (score 1):

See this your code is working fine for me & i am using Xcode 6 GM (iOS8 GM).

**Code:**

```
UIScrollView *MainScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
MainScroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
MainScroll.frame=CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 200);
[self.view addSubview:MainScroll];

UIView *HeaderView=[[UIView alloc]init];
HeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
HeaderView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20);
[MainScroll addSubview:HeaderView];
```

**iOS 8 Result :**

[image]

**iOS 7 Result :**

[image]

Comment: i too using GM only.Bt i m getting 20px Below from uiscrollview

Comment: can u try the same code after embed navigation controller

Comment: If i embed navigation controller it is placing after some spaces below scrollview..If i remove navigation controller it is placing below the scrollview